# CodeIgniter Missing Arguments Redirect to 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

If the user types `/apple/` instead of `/apple/1`, aka an undefined URL, it should redirect to the 404 page. However it goes to the controller and outputs a `Missing Argument1` message.

And I don't want to change:

```
public function index(){...}
```

To:

```
public function index($id = null){...}
```

Comment: Care to explain why not? It would be the most elegant and flexible solution. If the variable is empty, you redirect. Otherwise you'll need to work with routes, but then you'll have to update the routes file for every controller...

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, I didn't test it, but you could do:

in routes.php

```
$route['apple/(:any)'] = "apple";
$route['apple'] = "apple";
```

In apple.php

```
function index()
{
  if(!$this->uri->segment(1))
  {
    show_404();
  }
}
```